# How to change the port number of the mock service in SOAPUI

Tags: rest, mocking, soapui

I have ctreated a mock service in SOAPUI to mock a REST API web service. In default it has the port number set to 8080. I want to change this beacause already an application is running on that port. When I tried to edit the port number it is not allowing to edit. How to edit this?

[image: mock-service-properties]

And i have a customized domain for the URL i want to mock (example : http://core.sampleApp.io). So how do I enter this property to my mock service?

Answer (score 8):

[image: SoapUI screensnap]

Open your project. Scroll down to the Virts. Doubleclick on the one you want. Open the options. (Painted yellow in the screensnap above)

Answer (score 0):

You can "generate a new mockservice" but you have to take the choice of the mockservice that you have to change the port and change the port and press ok and the port will be changed.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] and increase clarity by splitting into more shorter sentences, maybe use a bulleted list of steps. Also, the post would benefit from a description of the effect of what you propose and an explanation of why that helps to solve the problem. Generally try for [answer].